# Закрытие дропдауна по клику на кнопку и ее соседнему элементу

Tags: javascript

Для кнопки пришлось добавить svg-стрелку, но по клику на неё дропдаун не работает, в консоли ошибка-"TypeError: ev.target.nextElementSibling is null". Как исправить код без использования свойства nextElementSibling?

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".header__dropdown-link").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    fnCloseAllDropdown(ev.target.nextElementSibling);
    ev.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("_show");
  });
});

document.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.closest("._show")) return;
  ev.stopPropagation();
  fnCloseAllDropdown();
});

function fnCloseAllDropdown(obj) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".painting-style__dropdown").forEach(el => {
    if (el != obj) {
      el.classList.remove("_show");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.btn-reset {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
}

.list-reset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
} 

.header__dropdown-link {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.painting-style__dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 300px;
  background: #cacaca;
}

._show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-reset header__dropdown-link nav-hover-style nav-focus-style">Кнопка
              <svg width="12" height="7" viewBox="0 0 12 7" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11 1L6 6L1 1" stroke="white"/>
</svg>
            </button>
            <ul class="list-reset painting-style__dropdown" data-simplebar>
              <li class="painting-style__dropdown-item"> <a class="link-reset painting-style__dropdown-link tintoretto"
                  href="#">Элемент 1</a> </li>
              <li class="painting-style__dropdown-item"> <a class="link-reset painting-style__dropdown-link fridrikh"
                  href="#">Элемент 2</a> </li>
              <li class="painting-style__dropdown-item"> <a class="link-reset painting-style__dropdown-link leonardo"
                  href="#">Элемент 3</a> </li>
              <li class="painting-style__dropdown-item"> <a class="link-reset painting-style__dropdown-link verokeoy"
                  href="#">Элемент 4</a> </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `pointer-events: none;` для содержимого кнопки:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".header__dropdown-link").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    fnCloseAllDropdown(ev.target.nextElementSibling);
    ev.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("_show");
  });
});

document.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.closest("._show")) return;
  ev.stopPropagation();
  fnCloseAllDropdown();
});

function fnCloseAllDropdown(obj) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".painting-style__dropdown").forEach(el => {
    if (el != obj) {
      el.classList.remove("_show");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.btn-reset {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
}
.btn-reset * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.list-reset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.header__dropdown-link {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.painting-style__dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 300px;
  background: #cacaca;
}

._show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-reset header__dropdown-link nav-hover-style nav-focus-style">Кнопка
  <svg width="12" height="7" viewBox="0 0 12 7" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11 1L6 6L1 1" stroke="white"/>
  </svg>
</button>
<ul class="list-reset painting-style__dropdown" data-simplebar>
  <li class="painting-style__dropdown-item"> <a class="link-reset painting-style__dropdown-link tintoretto" href="#">Элемент 1</a> </li>
  <li class="painting-style__dropdown-item"> <a class="link-reset painting-style__dropdown-link fridrikh" href="#">Элемент 2</a> </li>
  <li class="painting-style__dropdown-item"> <a class="link-reset painting-style__dropdown-link leonardo" href="#">Элемент 3</a> </li>
  <li class="painting-style__dropdown-item"> <a class="link-reset painting-style__dropdown-link verokeoy" href="#">Элемент 4</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Только и всего!) Благодарю, поставлю галку как только система разрешит)